# PyMongo: How to do bulk update of huge JSON data in MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm pulling JSON data from an API, with output like this:

```
[[{'employeeId': 1, 'lastName': 'Smith'}, {'employeeId': 2, 'lastName': 'Flores'}]]
```

There are about **250k** objects in the list. I am able to iterate through the objects in the list and do an `update_one` via **PyMongo** in this way:

```
json_this = json.dumps(json_list[0])
json_that = json.loads(json_this)
for x in json_that:
    collection.update_one({"employeeId": x['employeeId']},{"$set": x},upsert=True)
```

But with **250k** records this takes a long time. I'm trying to use `update_many` but can't figure out how to properly convert/format this list of JSON to use the `update_many` function. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want some like this : https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-update-multiple-mongodb-documents-in-python-359

Comment: @Chris A : Is this one time or regular process ?

Comment: @srinivasy probably once every 24 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating/Inserting  **250K** documents to database could be a hefty task, You cannot use `update_many` as the filter query and update values do change between each dictionary. So with this below query atleast you could avoid multiple calls to database but I'm not particularly sure how well this work for your scenario, Please note I'm beginner to python & this is a basic code to give you an idea :

The best thing you could do for bulk operation is [PyMongo-bulk](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html), due to limitations of [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html) we're splitting **250K** records into chunks :

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne
from pprint import pprint
import sys

json_this = json.dumps(json_list[0])
json_that = json.loads(json_this)

primaryBulkArr = []
secondaryBulkArr = []
thirdBulkArr = []

## Here we're splicing 250K records into 3 arrays, in case if we want to finish a chunk at a time,
 # No need to splice all at once - Finish end - to - end for one chunk & restart the process for another chunk from the index of the list where you left previously

for index, x in enumerate(json_that):
    if index < 90000:
        primaryBulkArr.append(
            UpdateOne({"employeeId": x['employeeId']}, {'$set': x}, upsert=True))
    elif index > 90000 and index < 180000:
        secondaryBulkArr.append(
            UpdateOne({"employeeId": x['employeeId']}, {'$set': x}, upsert=True))
    else:
        thirdBulkArr.append(
            UpdateOne({"employeeId": x['employeeId']}, {'$set': x}, upsert=True))

## Reason why I've spliced into 3 arrays is may be you can run below code in parallel if your DB & application servers can take it,
# At the end of the day irrespective of time taken only 3 DB calls are needed & this bulk op is much efficient.
try:
    result = collection.bulk_write(bulkArr)
    ## result = db.test.bulk_write(bulkArr, ordered=False)
    # Opt for above if you want to proceed on all dictionaries to be updated, even though an error occured in between for one dict
    pprint(result.bulk_api_result)
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print("An exception occurred ::", e) ## Get the ids failed if any & do re-try
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot to mention! I believe - "you don't need to splice 250k documents into multiple chunks" if your MongoDB driver is capable of doing chunks on its own.